# IONIC :: Vertical alignment of data inside an ion-list with an ion-checkbox

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm making an ion-list accompanied by ion-checkbox, but the data inside the list cells are displayed horizontally.

```
<ion-item class="item" *ngFor="let item of collection">
    <ion-label>{{ item.nameMother }}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{ item.nameChild }}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{ item.birthDate }}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{ item.Form }}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{ item.countdown }}</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

This is how it appears when I run it:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXbqs.png)

What can I do in order for the data to vertically align, instead of horizontally? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide your live code snippet using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: This has been resolved, thank you @core114 for answering.

Comment: You can provide your answer. lt's also helpful other users